# If can't eval identify empty string correctly in Firebird stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to create a procedure to automate some queries which are part of a search tool I'm creating.

```
create or alter procedure buscaExactPaisSS
    (palavra varchar(500))
returns
    (seriePK integer)
as
begin
    if (:palavra is null or :palavra = '') then
    begin
        for
            select seriesetorial.codserie
                from seriesetorial
                where codserie not in (select codserie from localidaderelset)
            into :seriePK
        do
        begin
            suspend;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        for
            select seriesetorial.codserie
                from seriesetorial, localidade, localidaderelset
                where lower(localidade.nome) = lower(:palavra)
                    and localidaderelset.codlocalidade = localidade.codlocalidade
                    and seriesetorial.codserie = localidaderelset.codserie
                into :seriePK
        do
        begin
            suspend;
        end
    end
end!
```

However, the procedure always returns the result for the first case, that is, when `palavra` is either null or ''. Why is that? How do I fix this?

Edit - 16/03/2017:

This function is actually right. Hope this at least serves as an example of a working procedure with variable usage for FB's PSQL.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your stored procedure, except that you use `:palavra` instead of `palavra` (without the `:`!)). How do you call it? You might want to double check if your stored procedure is actually what you think it is (by checking the source in the database), maybe the component you used to execute the create procedure statement replaced the `:palavra` with `null`.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that the function is right. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your code outside of a stored procedure. If you simplify it a bit, you can see that both conditions get a chance to be executed correctly:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE BUSCAEXACTPAISSS (PALAVRA VARCHAR(500))
RETURNS (
    SERIEPK INTEGER
)
AS
begin
    if (:palavra is null or :palavra = '') then
    begin
        for
            select 0 FROM someTable
            into :seriePK
        do
        begin
            suspend;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        for
            select 1 FROM someTable
                into :seriePK
        do
        begin
            suspend;
        end
    end
end;
```

Try #1:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE buscaExactPaisSS '77'
```

> 1

Try #2:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE buscaExactPaisSS ''
```

> 0

Comment: You are absolutelly right, I must've been very tired and tried to use an invalid  input for the procedure, that is, a value to which the return value was empty.